# How to Change UITextField When Editing

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitextfield

I have multiple UITextField's in my view controller which is also a text field delegate. For some reason, the following code only works when you select a text field after not having any selected. If I switch between text fields then the text field I am leaving changes, but the one I am now editing does not change to red. I debugged and found that both methods are called even when switching in between the two, but for some reason, it just does not set the color for the one you are now editing. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    self.setTextBorder(textField: textField, color: UIColor.red)
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
     self.setTextBorder(textField: textField, color: UIColor.lightGray)
}

func setTextBorder(textField: UITextField, color: UIColor) {
    let border = CALayer()
    let width = CGFloat(2.0)
    border.borderColor = color.cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textField.frame.size.height - width, width:  textField.frame.size.width, height: textField.frame.size.height)
    border.borderWidth = width
    textField.layer.addSublayer(border)
    textField.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

**EDIT**

I now created a custom class to test and see if the issue was the fact that I kept adding sublayers. I am getting the same results. Here is the custom text field class I made:

```
class SpecialTextField: UITextField {

    var currentBorder: CALayer?

    func setTextBorder(color: UIColor) {
        let border = CALayer()
        let width = CGFloat(2.0)
        border.borderColor = color.cgColor
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        border.borderWidth = width
        if (currentBorder == nil) {
            self.layer.addSublayer(border)
            self.layer.masksToBounds = true

        } else {
            self.layer.replaceSublayer(self.currentBorder!, with: border)
        }
        self.currentBorder = border
    }

}
```

Comment: You keep adding more and more layers to a given text field as you change focus back and forth.

Comment: @rmaddy That is true. However, I don't believe that should effect when the method works.

Comment: @rmaddy I have updated the question with what I tried to avoid repeatedly adding more layers. Same result.

Comment: @Kendel what do you want ? When user start typing then border color is red and when leave that textfiled its bordercolor change to gray color ? If you want to do like this then follow my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453124/change-the-border-color-of-uitextfield/41456424#41456424 Just change color as per you want. In this answer I set only border color of bottom so you have to set all sides

Comment: @JeckyModi Thanks for the idea, but that is the same thing I am doing and it is not working. You are just using outlets directly from the text fields rather than using the delegate methods. Same results.

Comment: ok, you want to do it with delegate method then I will make it with it So, soon reply to you

Comment: Did you set textfield.delegate = self and UITextFieldDelegate ?

Comment: @JeckyModi The issue is with the drawing of the layers, because otherwise it would never work. Also, I have now solved the issue, please check out the answer I posted. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to set the initial border color I was using `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, which was causing the issue. It was overriding the layers I was changing during editing.

Answer (score 0):

you should change text color in

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
    {
       // textfield.backgrounColor = UIColor.yourselectedcolor
        return true
    }
```

then revert color back in endEditing delegate method.

Comment: That will not help. That just makes it so the background changes when they start typing characters. The same issue is still occurring regardless. For some reason, when switching between the text views something strange happens that doesn't allow for me to change the layer.

Comment: are you using any kind of keyboard library ? to handle keyboard in your project?

Comment: i think you should try in dispatch if the functions are calling but UI is not update at current time.