# Change the border color of uitextfield

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I added bottom border to `UITextField` this way:

```
let bottomLine = CALayer()
bottomLine.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, self.frame.height, self.frame.width, CGFloat(borderWidth))
bottomLine.backgroundColor = borderColor.CGColor
self.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
self.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)
```

How can I change the border color of this bottom line when `UITextField` call `textFieldDidBeginEditing()` and then change back color to default when it calls `textFieldDidEndEditing()`

I'm using a custom class of `UITextField`

Comment: Have you assigned the textfield's delegate property to an object that conforms to the UITextField delegate protocol? And have you implemented the textFieldDidBeginEditing() and textFieldDidEndEditing() functions in this delegate?

Comment: Yes, I have. I just don't know how to change the `bottomLine` properties that I added in `sublayer`.

Comment: @Amirhosseingholzam please check my answer, It works fine according to your expectation, just give your colors you want in end editing and did begin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take Action methods of `textfield` as `editing did begin and editing did end`

This will work fine, I have tested it

```
   @IBAction func didbegin(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let border = CALayer()
        let width = CGFloat(2.0)
        border.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: txtfield.frame.size.height - width, width:  txtfield.frame.size.width, height: txtfield.frame.size.height)

        border.borderWidth = width
        txtfield.layer.addSublayer(border)
        txtfield.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }


    @IBAction func endediting(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let border = CALayer()
        let width = CGFloat(2.0)
        border.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: txtfield.frame.size.height - width, width:  txtfield.frame.size.width, height: txtfield.frame.size.height)

        border.borderWidth = width
        txtfield.layer.addSublayer(border)
        txtfield.layer.masksToBounds = true

    }
```

Hope this thing helps you.

Comment: There is no different between your answer and another except you wrote it in swift 3. Anyhow, thanks for your answer. The problem is, with your code should add many extra `layer` in per event but I need to optimize my app.And when I put this code in `layoutSubviews` for default appearance it doesn't work for edit events.

Comment: As according your question, I think your problem is solved. This code only works with outlet So if you want this with all textfield then U should use its delegate method for this or U can give same outlet for every textfield

Answer (score 1):

Try just re-adding the layer with the default color in the textFieldDidEndEditing method, like so:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) { 
        let bottomLine = CALayer()
         bottomLine.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, self.frame.height, self.frame.width, CGFloat(borderWidth))
        bottomLine.backgroundColor = borderColor.CGColor
        self.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
        self.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)
    }

 func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    let bottomLine = CALayer()
    bottomLine.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, self.frame.height, self.frame.width, CGFloat(borderWidth))
    bottomLine.backgroundColor = defaultColor.CGColor
    self.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
    self.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)
}
```

This worked for me

Comment: Thanks :) but it doesn't work for me :(. Even if I used this way I should add many `extra layer` but  I need to optimize my app.

Answer (score 0):

```
    func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let border = CALayer()
        let width = CGFloat(2.0)
        border.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: yourTextFeild.frame.size.height - width, width:  yourTextFeild.frame.size.width, height: yourTextFeild.frame.size.height)

        border.borderWidth = width
        yourTextFeild.layer.addSublayer(border)
        yourTextFeild.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }   

 //Mark Textfield Delegate
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        for layer in  textField.layer.sublayers!{
            layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor

      }
   }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        for layer in  textField.layer.sublayers!{
            layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor   
        }
    }
```